# Meteor + accounts-facebook redirecting to wrong url

Tags: facebook, nginx, meteor, url-routing

I'm currently developing on my server, not on my personal computer, but it seems to be impossible to tell it to Meteor, as I'm trying to use Facebook login. The expected login url for `app.example.com` is

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=http://app.example.com/_oauth/facebook?close&<more junk>
```

But I always get

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close&<more junk>
```

I'm using Nginx as a proxy for Meteor server, so I should be able to access it pointing to `app.example.com`, but Meteor seems to not detect it. Where is it changeable?

Comment: Can you provide the code which is generating the url above?

Comment: I don't know where it is. I just downloaded the packages `accounts-facebook` and inserted `{{loginButtons}}` to my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the environment value ROOT_URL before executing meteor, i.e.

```
ROOT_URL=http://app.example.com meteor run
```